# ListView Indexable?

Tags: android, android-listview

I need to have a `ListView Indexable` that when i `click` on a number it redirect me to a `row` that the `index` of `row` be same the number of `ListView Indexable`. For example when I `click` on 2 , it redirect me to it `row` that the number of `index` (`ListView`) is 2 .

[image]

Comment: Check : http://simpleandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2013/04/indexable-listview-tutorial-source-code.html

Comment: No it find base first character of listView . I need find base (Index) of ListView .Thanks

Comment: you can use index instead of Alphabet.

Comment: I insert number instead alphabetic but when i click on a number it find Row base first character but i need find base number index of listView . give me your mail that I mail my project for you .

Comment: I send for you ,check your mail . Thanks .

Comment: try to check my ans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

If you dont wan to change any code in IndexScroller class then Change below code in your SimpleAdapter class.

Right section value as no item in list.

```
private String[] mSections;

public SimpleAdapter(ArrayList<String> mCurrentList, Context mContext) {
    super();
    this.mCurrentList = mCurrentList;
    mSections = new String[mCurrentList.size()];
    for(int i=0;i<mCurrentList.size();i++){
        mSections[i] = String.valueOf(i+1);
    }
    this.mContext = mContext;
}
```

Try given selected right side section value to move list.

```
@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
    return section;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I see your project in `IndexScroller.java` in `onTouchEvent` comment this line :

```
//mListView.setSelection(mIndexer.getPositionForSection(mCurrentSection));
```

Then add :

```
for (int i = 1; i < count; i++) {
                    if(mCurrentSection == i){
                        mListView.setSelection(mCurrentSection);
                    }
                }
```

Now you can work . ;)
This example is from :

```
http://simpleandroidcoding.blogspot.in/2013/04/indexable-listview-tutorial-source-code.html
```

With The difference that you should add number to `indexable` and then find `Rows` base `IDS Rows`.